# Is "if you say so" considered offensive or polite refusal?

Tags: grammar

Literally the title!

If somebody says some statement and I really don't believe it and said " if you say so, dude". Would that be considered offensive or polite refusal?

Comment: Depends on the tone and your relationship with that person. It could mean you agreed to disagree, or you believe they are a liar.

Comment: With a former partner, I used to say "I expect you're right", to indicate that I disagreed with  them but was not willing to argue about it. They found it irritating but couldn't really take offence, because technically I was agreeing with them. "If you say so" has the same kind of tone. Irritating, maybe, but certainly not offensive. It should be OK with somebody that you know well.

Comment: Considering she was your former partner, she might have been upset about something else hehe:)

Comment: It's pretty much on a par with responding ***Whatever*** to something someone just told you. Basically they both mean ***I couldn't care less*** (*I **could** care less* for Americans! :) which is equivalent to saying *I'm not interested in what you said* (often implying lack of interest *...in **anything** you say*). Sounds pretty dismissive / insulting to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using "dude" puts this into the very casual setting. Using "dude" is fine between two friends at a pub, but would be inappropriate in a semi-formal context, such as speaking to a work colleague or on an internet forum such as this.

"If you say so" suggests that you don't really believe what the person says, but you don't want to argue about it.  As such it is rather dismissive. It means you think the person is wrong, but don't care enough about it even to explain why you think they are wrong.

It can mean "I trust your opinion enough that I will accept it even though I don't believe it" or "I think you are wrong, but I hope we can agree to disagree" or "Your opinion is worthless and wrong, and there is no point discussing this."

So whether that is friendly or insulting depends so much on the context that no single answer can be given. Learners will rarely be in situation in which using "dude" or "if you say so dude" is an appropriate response.